# Error message: WickrMe: undefined symbol

Tags: linux

So I got an error message WickrMe: symbol lookup error: WickrMe: undefined symbol: _ZNK6google8protobuf7Message11GetTypeNameB5cxx11Ev

I installed WickrMe on my Linux Mint 19.1 64 bit and I want to start it but it gives me this error

I figured out from searching that I would have to reinstall the library what is defined in the error, but I have no LibQt or something like that in this.

update: reinstalling libprotobuf not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So now I know that I made a lot of unnecessary things to get it in working shape, so if you have the same issue here's the WickrMe supports answer:
"I'd suggest uninstalling what you have now and trying it from here: https://snapcraft.io/search?q=wickr "
So try that, this works for me